# Comparison between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to pull in an ID number and name from one table that checks to see if the same ID number does not exist in another table. I am getting the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value.

Below is my query.

```
Select Table1.ID,
       Table1.Name
  From Table1
 Where Table1.ID not in ((select (Table2.ID)
                            from Table2 ) 
                         COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
```

Comment: Where is the collate supposed to apply to -- no point on to change it when comparing an id, which one assumes is numeric data.

Answer (score 6):

Would it not be a **lot** easier to do:

```
SELECT Table1.ID,
       Table1.Name
FROM   Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
WHERE  Table2.ID is null
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say it would be a **lot** easier (not entirely certain I'd say it's *easier* at all), but this is how I would have written said query.

Comment: I tend to use `NOT EXISTS` for these http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/

Comment: @Martin And I learn soemthing new everyday -- didn't realise they would perform so differently with the correct indexes

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses and `collate` are either unneeded or in the wrong place but I can't get the same error as you are getting.

```
with Table1(ID, Name) aS
(
SELECT 'A1',2 union all
select 'B1',2
),
Table2(ID, Name) aS
(
SELECT 'A1',2 union all
select 'D1',2
)

Select Table1.ID,
       Table1.Name
  From Table1
 Where Table1.ID not in (select Table2.ID   COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
                            from Table2 )
```

works fine. You should favour `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN` on nullable columns but I assume the `ID` field is unlikely to be NULLABLE?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can never get "Subquery returned more than 1 value." with a `Not in` The OP probably had a `<>` or `=` in there at some point.

Answer (score 0):

The `COLLATE` statement only applies to an expression, not to a set. Are you certain that you actually *need* to specify a collation here? If so, you need to move it inside the subselect, so that it reads this way:

```
select Table2.ID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS from Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

This part...

```
((select (Table2.ID) from Table2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
```

seems to be collecting the list of rows... Try removing the `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`

and just use:

```
(select (Table2.ID) from Table2)  )
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

The best performing query for a non-existence test is to ... use NOT-exists.
The worktable does not need to collect all rows of the LEFT JOIN just to `PRUNE` later using the WHERE clause.  The first existence match aborts the table1 row.

```
Select Table1.ID,
       Table1.Name
  From Table1
 Where NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   from Table2
                   WHERE Table2.ID = TABLE1.ID)
```